# How can I group a list based on a similar value

Tags: list, kotlin, grouping

I have a list of highscores, and I would like to group it into lists for each category the highscores belong to.

My data classes look like this

```kotlin
data class HighScore(val word: Word)
data class Word(val category: String)
```

I was doing something like this.

```kotlin
val highScores = listOf<HighScore>(...)
val groupedScores = highScores.groupBy{ it:HighScore
    it.word.category
}
```

What I am trying to do is to get all the high-scores with a similar category and put them into separate lists, I am sure there must be a function for that in kotlin, but I only seem to be able to find tutorials that explains how to group lists by number values and not predicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the right `groupBy` function that takes a predicate, but your lambda syntax is wrong.

Either add an arrow:

```
val groupedScores = highScores.groupBy{ it:HighScore ->
    it.word.category
}
```

or remove the parameter entirely to use the implicit single parameter `it`:

```
val groupedScores = highScores.groupBy{
    it.word.category
}
```